# Bad GUI resolution WSL2

Tags: resolution, windows-subsystem-for-linux, window, gui

Today I updated to Windows Insider Preview 21387.1 and run `wsl --update` to use the new GUI feature of WSL2. (no extra software like VcXsrv or etc.)
After restarting WSL, I could run GUI apps like gnome calculator, nautilus and... but there is a problem: apps look a little streched.
[image]
It's like when I run a full screen game with 640x480 resolution on my 1366x768 screen. Items look bigger than usual and are streched.
I installed AMD driver for WSL (secondary GPU is AMD Radeon R7 M265). Couldn't install Intel GPU drivers as they were for 5th gen and newer CPUs and my CPU is Core i7-4500U.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Windows Insider Preview is not a stable release, problems are to be expected. Best to report the problem to Microsoft.

Comment: There are many issues with WSLg feature, see here https://github.com/microsoft/wslg